# Comparing two XML Schemas

Tags: xml, comparison, xsd

Are there any tools to effectively compare two XML schema's?  I have seen some generic XML diff tools, but I was wondering if there is anything that knows more about schemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into [DeltaXML](http://www.deltaxml.com/).  It seems to have the features you're looking for.  They even have a guide on [how to compare schemas](http://www.deltaxml.com/dxml/library/how-to-compare-schemas.html).

Comment: Thanks! Their demo page compares XSDs just like I want: http://www.deltaxml.com/products/core/demo?demo=schema

Comment: As for me leaning curve was too huge for this product. It also has no GUI on Windows.