# FOSS (command line) tools for XML Schema (XSD) comparison?

Tags: command-line, xsd, comparison

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433/comparing-two-xml-schemas) are there any free/open source, (*nix) command-line tools that can compare and report on the differences between two XML Schema Documents (XSDs)?

I'm specifically looking for something I can introduce to a programmatic workflow to report updates to an XSD out of my control, but which I must conform to/validate against.

Comment: There are no such tools - and I assume you want the real thing, similar to what I've described [here](http://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/comparing-xsd-files.aspx). If your interest is that high (judging from the bounty size), we could work something out regarding the **free** part, assuming that i) the compare that we have indeed satisfies what your needs are (you could asses that for free on a windows workstation) and ii) that it would actually work on Mono (which may support your *nix flavour) which in return you would have to help testing since we're not supporting Mono...

Comment: (cont'd) What we have is designed to support [command line interfaces](http://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/command-line-interface.aspx) for Continuous Integration along the same lines you're looking for, but supported on Windows only. If you're interested to chat more, drop me an email through the support address on my website.

Comment: Is Python an option, as there are e.g.
[lxml](http://lxml.de/)
[generateDS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/generateDS/)
[pyxb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxb/)
?

Comment: @thoku yes, Python is an option, but I've not found a lib that will already do a direct logic=logic comparison of XMLSchema. I'd have to build it myself, and that's not something I'm particularly interested in doing.

Answer (score -1):

This problem reduces to "a free XML diff program", as an XSD file is just a specific type of XML file.

One cheap solution is to pretty-print the XSD files, then use a standard text difference program on the pretty-pinted XSD files. There are free programs for both of those tasks.

Comment: I don't think it does. There is logic within XSD files that can be represented using slightly different markup. This would mean that two XSDs can be grammatically/syntactically different but logically the same, and therefore a simple XML diff wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: It may be like blowing my own horn here, but have a look at [this link](http://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/comparing-xsd-files.aspx). If anything, just look at the Tiny schema versions, and for sure you'll see an example of what @unpluggd talks about. The funny thing is that the accepted answer to the question referenced in the post points to a tool that does exactly what you've said...

Comment: A comment, order, not setting values that are default,... would all show as a difference when they functionally don't matter.